# AWS EC2 w/ Ubuntu running out of space

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, resource-cleanup

I have continuous integration workflow set up on my AWS EC2, which is working great, yet is filling up through time while the application isn't growing.

It seems to be due to AWS update files that are difficult to remove.

I've tried to use:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

When I run:

```
sudo du -cha --max-depth=1 / | grep -E "M|G"
```

It shows that I have 2.0G in my `/tmp` folder and 1.5G in my `/usr` directory.

In my usr directory, the src folder seems to be filled with files like `linux-aws-headers-4.4.0-1049`

Is it safe to delete all contents of the `/tmp` folder, and what is the best way to clean up the old build files located in `/usr/src` ?

Comment: Is this instance store or EBS?  In general you don't know if it's safe to remove stuff from `/tmp` - it very well might be but they may still be in use.  2GB is 1/3 of what my phone has - why can't you allocate a bit more space?

Comment: Hi @stdunbar, could allocate more space, yet then Amazon would charge me more $$. Mostly curious about how to properly clean up their build files in a way to maintain the instance over time. It is an EBS backed instance on my staging server, so am willing to try things out in terms of server-based house keeping.

Comment: Well 2TB is about USD $3.30/month but `apt-get clean` is the standard way of getting rid of apt files that are no longer needed as you already have.  That removes files from `/var/cache/apt/archives`.  Again, `/tmp` is variable - a build may leave files there that can be removed once it's done running.

Comment: Okay, emptied a folder `/tmp/v8-compile-cache-1000` which cleared up 2Gs. Seemed to be relics from node and webpack. Was mostly curious if there is a standard approach to clean up old build files on a EC2, yet guessing it is more of a seek and destroy operation.